# anchors links won't work after building the APK - Ionic / Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I tested my application through Ionic View, everything worked, the links usually done with the anchor with the normal href tag of the html. Everything was working, but then when I did the build, when I clicked on the link it bugged and it would not open or leave the App to start an external App through the link as it did through the Ionic view.

The link was this way:

```
<a href="tel:{{rest?.telefone}}" target="_blank">{{rest?.telefone}}</a>
```

Comment: Try `ng-href` instead of href

Comment: Already tried, but in the angular2 is `[href]` instead of `ng-href`, and not working too.

Comment: Actually why there is a `?` after `rest`? I learned few about ts but don't know that usage.

Comment: `?` is like a `if` he verify `if exist the variable rest`, so he get the value from `rest.telefone` if true

Comment: I'm starting to think this is a problem with Whitelist not working for me as .apk, because in Ionic View the anchors work.

Comment: But I tried in my ionic 1 project to attach `?` to my expression, they are not working. Did I miss something? Can you give me an official doc about that usage?

Comment: Could you please inspect the html code when opening the app in the device? Maybe it's related to the dom sanitizer. If not, then definitely is related to whitelist not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line to your `config.xml`.

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
```